# The kernel (user Python environment) has terminated with error code -11

Tags: python, canopy

I use threading to create a module and the following error message. I don't know what exactly is wrong with the following code. Can anyone give me some clue?

Error Message:
The kernel (user Python environment) has terminated with error code -11. This may be due to a bug in your code or in the kernel itself.
If you were using a pre-Jupyter Canopy and have not already updated the "ipython" package in the Canopy Package Manager, please do so now, then restart the kernel.

```
    class Counter:
        def __init__(self):
            self.lock=threading.Lock() #define a lock attribute
            self.value=0               #define a value attribute

        def increment(self):
            self.lock.acquire() #acquire the global lock
            self.value=self.value+1 #the value variable can only be accessed by one thread
            self.lock.release() #release the lock
            return self.value

        def v(self):
            return self.value
    c=Counter() #define a global counter variable

    class SelectedStockList:
        def __init__(self):
            self.lock=threading.Lock()
            self.value=[]

        def add_item(self,item):
            self.lock.acquire()
            self.value.append(item)
            self.lock.release()
            return self.value

        def get_value(self):
            return self.value
    selectedStockList=SelectedStockList() #define a list to store the stock

    class Worker(threading.Thread):
        """ Thread worker for selecting stocks in input list"""
        def __init__(self,StockList):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.StockList=StockList

        def run(self):
            #global c
            global selectedStockList
            for i in self.StockList:
                print "Threadname=", self.getName()
                print "Active Threads=", threading.active_count()
                result=SelectStockRule(i)
                #c.increment()
                #print "Counter=", c.v()
                print "Result=", result
                if result != False:
                    selectedStockList.add_item(str(result))
                print "selectedStockList=", selectedStockList.get_value()
                print "............................................................"
                time.sleep(0.1)

    def workDistributor(stockList,threadCounts):
        """Distribute work to workers"""
        #Total 
        TOTAL=len(stockList)
        reshapedList=np.array(stockList).reshape(threadCounts,(TOTAL/threadCounts))
        for i in reshapedList:
            Worker(i).start()

    # Read mainboard stock into list
    FILE='~/Desktop/PandasFinance/MainBoardList.txt'                        
    MainBoardStockList=CleanStock(FILE)
    MainBoardStockList=MainBoardStockList[0:2000]
    workDistributor(MainBoardStockList,10)
```

Comment: What's the minimum code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @PeterWood What do you mean by minimum code?
There is no Track back error.
For the source code, please check my [github repository](https://github.com/extremewaysback/PythonMultithreading.git)

Comment: How much code can you delete and still have the problem? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @peterwood I see. After test, I found that there is a problem with the ---SelectStockRule ---function. After disable that function, everything else is fine. After improving the that function, the problem has been solved, thank you very much